# WCF Serialization of POCO EF nested class?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, service

I have a problem. I have a WCF service as my data access to my Entity Framework. I need to return some objects. This is my first model:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Osoba
{
    [DataMember]
    public int IdOsobe { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PrezimeOsobe { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ImeOsobe { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Partner Partner { get; set; }
}
```

This is my second model:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Partner
{
    public Partner()
    {
        this.Dokument = new HashSet<Dokument>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int IdPartnera { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OIB { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int TipPartnera { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> IdMjestaSjedista { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AdrSjedista { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> IdMjestaIsporuke { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AdrIsporuke { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Dokument> Dokument { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Mjesto Mjesto { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Mjesto Mjesto1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Osoba Osoba { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Tvrtka Tvrtka { get; set; }
}
```

When my service returns Osoba, Partner reference object is not serialized. Partner = null. What am I doing wrong? I've tried with ServiceKnownType attribute, nothing.

Comment: What kind of serialization do you use?

Comment: Default WCF DataContractSerializer. I even disabled lazy laoding for all entities - nothing

Comment: How do you load the Partner property? Are you sure you are loading it?

Comment: Everything is working until return from service. I have Include(p=>p.Partner) in my service. I have included what I need. Result is ok, Partners are loaded everything works until return. It actually returns, just not Partner property = null

Comment: Perhaps the proxy classes are misleading the data contract serializer. Try to cast them explicitly (`Osoba` object, and `Partner` property) to the entity classes before returning them and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. Proxy was not a problem because I used this for my proxies [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee705457(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee705457%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
The problem was one line of code in EF - context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Detached. Every included entity was actually detached. I've put a comment on that and everything is working. Thank you all very much